# How to find how many pixel long a line is

Tags: java, java-2d

I am drawing lines using `drawLine` method in Java. I know beginning and end points of lines.

1. How can I measure the length of lines as pixels?
2. If I am working on a `BufferedImage` whose width and height are determined by `Dimension(500,500)`, do the points which determine the start and the end of a line correspond to the pixels? Then will calculating only the distance of two points be sufficient for measuring the pixel length of line?

Comment: I would think yes and yes. Why don't you write your image to a jpg file, open it with gimp or whatever image editor you prefer and measure the distance yourself just to be sure?

Comment: What exactly is the "pixel length" of an oblique line? The total number of black (or whatever color) pixels? I guess this will also depend on how exactly the line is drawn, anti-aliasing and all...

Answer (score 1):

The `BufferedImage` works in an integer; Cartesian space. So each pixel corresponds to a point.

Use the [distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry) to determine the length, if you have the points.

```
int distance = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

---

If you are using the `Point2D` class for your points, there are multiple methods to make this easier for you to determine distance.

- [`double distance(double px, double py)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance(double,%20double))

  - Returns the distance from this Point2D to a specified point.
- [`static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance(double,%20double,%20double,%20double))

  - Returns the distance between two points.
- [`double distance(Point2D pt)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance(java.awt.geom.Point2D))

  - Returns the distance from this Point2D to a specified Point2D.
- [`double distanceSq(double px, double py)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distanceSq(double,%20double))

  - Returns the square of the distance from this Point2D to a specified point.
- [`static double distanceSq(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distanceSq(double,%20double,%20double,%20double))

  - Returns the square of the distance between two points.
- [`double distanceSq(Point2D pt)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distanceSq(java.awt.geom.Point2D))

  - Returns the square of the distance from this Point2D to a specified Point2D.